# Combining several routes for API nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, routes

I'm creating an API and have several routes. My folder structure looks like the following

```
-api
 -controllers
 -routes
  -videoRoutes
  -userRoutes
  -mainRoutes
 -server
```

Inside my routes are my API calls. Below is an example of my api routes in userRoutes

```
 module.exports = function(app) {
var user = require('../controllers/userController');

//user routes
app.route('/api/v1.0/users/getAllUsers')
    .get(user.getAllUsers);

app.route('/api/v1.0/users/login')
    .post(user.login);    

app.route('/api/v1.0/users/addUser')
    .post(user.addUser);
```

};

The game route follows a similiar structure layout. I want to have one main route which contains all the other routes and then just reference that in my server.js. To do this I have tried the following in the main routes folder

```
var mainRoutes = module.exports = function(app) {
require('./userRoutes');
require('./gameRoutes');
};
```

The in my server.js I have attempted to call the mainRoutes in the following way

```
 var routes = require('./api/routes/mainRoutes')
 routes(app);
```

However, this doesn't work and none of the API calls work when trying to call them on the front end. My code works fine as if I combine the two files (merging manually) it works but trying to combine using module exports seems to fail? What am I doing wrong? How can have the routes seperate in two js files and have a mainRouter and then just reference that in my server.js?

Also if this is bad practise or anyone has any suggestions of alternative methods please let me know.

Comment: Does making the following change help?   `var mainRoutes = module.exports = function(app) {  
require('./userRoutes')(app);  
require('./gameRoutes')(app);  
};`

Comment: Yes thank you very much. It now works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

`var mainRoutes = module.exports = function(app) {
require('./userRoutes')(app);
require('./gameRoutes')(app);
};`

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you change your mainRoutes file to this:

```
var mainRoutes = module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(require('./userRoutes'));
  app.use(require('./gameRoutes'));
};
```

Also, make sure you're exporting the router from the individual routes.

Comment: I think I've been unclear. I have 2 seperate files. One userRouter and one VideoRouter. I want to then reference these in a mainRouter file and then only call the mainRouter from my main application file. Is this possible?

Comment: Thank you very much. But that's not working for me. As per PerterVC the following worked var mainRoutes = module.exports = function(app){ 
    require('./userRoutes')(app); 
 
    require('./gameRoutes')(app); };  If you edit your answer I can give it the tick so others can see it in the future